# mysql don't connect without running XAMPP mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP before to create database of my application with it but when I tried to delete it and use mysql server it didn't connect to server till I downloaded XAMPP again and connect to mysql in XAMPP so mysql server connect successfully, now I want to use mysql server without XAMPP what can I do for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download MySql and run the same as a service.

Download it from here https://www.mysql.com/downloads.

Now after installing it, you can run Mysql as service just by following the below steps:

1. Press windows + R.
2. Write services.msc
3. Find the mysql service in the popup and select the same.
4. On selecting it, you can see few options appearing on the left panel. Click no start service.

You will be able to connect to mysql then.

Comment: I did that steps and when I tried to open workbench I get page which appear that that server status is stopped

Comment: You might need to look into the error logs. Please let me know what you have in the logs and make sure no other program is blocking the port.

Comment: in error logs I have error said that 'Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306'
Yes I'm sure that no other program is blocking the port because XAMPP mysql was work with this port

Comment: I want to use MySQL without needing to run mysql from XAMPP

Comment: now I found the socket which workbench use is the XAMPP mysql socket , how can I solve this ?

Comment: You mean the port, right? Have you started the mysql service through services.msc? And can you please try connecting mysql after uninstalling XAMPP? Maybe multiple instances of mysql is present and that's why you might be facing some conflict.